# I use operator ">>" in shell script, assuming to append the log file.But there is something wrong

Tags: shell, file-io, io-redirection

This is the function I use to write logs.

```
log() {
        DATE=`date`
        echo "[$DATE] $1" >> "$SCRIPT_DIR/auto.log"
```

}

This script runs 1 time per minute, and Every time it truncated the log file and then append the file.I use tail to see what happens, and it appears:

tail: auto.log: file truncated

The function is the only place I use the auto.log in the script, why it truncated when the script start every time ?

Comment: looks correct to me, maybe something outside of this code is wrong.

Comment: The only problem I see is that you need either a `;` or a newline before the final `}`. As written, the `}` is simply an argument to `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it is working for me. this is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

log() {
        DATE=`date`
        echo "[$DATE] $1" >> "${SCRIPT_DIR}/auto.log"
}

SCRIPT_DIR="/home"
log
```

I cannot imaging how your script run without error. I think your function's parenthesis is the problem here. check it out.

Thanks.

Comment: I made a mistake when inputing the program on web. The script works, but the problem is it always clear the auto.log file and append to in the new one.